# How to get DBLink name in ODI KM

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dblink, oracle-data-integrator

I'm using Oracle Data Integration and i need to integrate in an IKM a source DBLink.

I have a simple mapping between one source table and one target table. The source table is on another database so I need to use a `DBLink`.
I have created the `DBLink` in the topology and associated to the source Data Server.

I tried to "catch" the DBLink name using `<%=odiRef.getInfo("SRC_DSERV_NAME")%>` but i get the target instance instead of source `DBLink(instance).`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add application or technology related tags so that the experts can find it to answer your question

Comment: Great. You can add your solution as the answer so that it can he be helpful to others. And add any reference which helped you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I've found the solution: `<@=odiRef.getObjectName("R","<%=odiRef.getSrcTablesList("", "[TABLE_NAME]", "", "")%>","D")@>`.